# Android sendBroadcast - waiting for BroadcastReceiver to finish

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using a `BroadcastReceiver` in my Android app which simply contains the following piece of code:

```
public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GcmIntentService.isHandled = true;
        Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast receiver test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I'm using this receiver to determine if my activity is running and carry out some updates in a ListView without having any notifications produced by GcmIntentService.

With the code being simple so far, only creating a toast message, I'm unable to catch the boolean value from `GcmIntentService.isHandled` as soon as the `sendBroadcast` is invoked.

Is it possible in any way to determine if the code for my receiver has finished running. I understand that `sendBroadcast` is an asynchronous call, and I'm making use of `Thread.sleep(1000)` so far to wait for the isHandled value, but it would be nice if there is a more reliable method on achieving this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you calling `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: in my `GcmIntentService` class that extends `IntentService`

Comment: You need to show more code. Your architecture is unclear, and your problem is also unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be divided to two parts:

1.How to know that if there is a receiver actually received the broadcast.

2.How should the receiver notify the service that message is been handled.

It seems difficult to achieve the first goal through standard Intent api, instead I suggest you may try the "observer pattern".

You may create a global [Observable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html) object in your Application and make your Activity implements [Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html), register itself in onCreate() and unRegister in onDestory().Inside the Service you can check if there is an Activity running through [countObservers()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html#countObservers%28%29) and then simply notify it.